# How to add my own ebooks in mobi format to be displayed in Kindle app on Android

Tags: kindle-app, android

In older versions of Android/Kindle App, it used to be enough to drop any `.mobi` files into the 'kindle' folder on SD Card, but in latest version of Kindle app, they still don't show up as books on 'On Device'. Did that location change, or is this approach no longer possible at all? I also turned on 'enable personal documents stored on your data storage to appear in your kindle library' setting, but no effect.

Comment: For the Kindle 10-th generation this folder is named `documents`

Answer (score 2):

Each Kindle device should have an email address where you email the books. Find system settings on your device to find that email address. Email the mobi file as an attachment to that email address.

Answer (score 0):

If you sideload,  I suspect your easiest solution would be to install an android reading system like FBReader. https://fbreader.org/FBReaderJ It definitely reads ebook on a card (though you have to change defaults).

But if you have .mobi files you'd like to transfer, I still think it would be easier to send it to your Kindle device https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_pdoc_main_short_us?nodeId=200767340

Things to check when troubleshooting Personal Doc storage (which in general, works great).

Did you 1)add the sending email to your list of approved addresses? 2)Did you send it to the device email of the correct device? 3)Did you verify on the Personal Documents Service that the ebook was received? https://www.amazon.com/mn/dcw/myx.html#/home/content/booksAll/dateDsc/  (Hint: you should filter results by DOCS and not by BOOKS to see content you uploaded).

At the top of the URL, it should say, "show DOCS" instead of "show BOOKS"

If you see your uploaded ebook correctly there, choose the dropdown to make sure it was delivered to the correct device.

Comment: I believe the question was about how to sideload into Kindle app specifically (rather than into any ebook reading app).

Comment: I have transferred .mobi files to some e-ink Kindles before (I think I put it just in the root). But again, unless you are trying to avoid using an Amazon account, or lack access to wifi it is much easier to use Amazon's Personal Docs service.